# Turn preamble font declaration into a "oneliner" to be used in Matlab

Tags: fonts, matlab

I was already using `x` and `y`, and needed something similar, but different so I declared the following in my preamble:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{pzc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}{<-> s * [1.10] pzcmi7t}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
```

This means I can use `\mathpzc{x}` and `\mathpzc{y}` in my document. However, I have now made a figure in Matlab and want to use `\mathpzc{x}` and `\mathpzc{y}` along the axis.

I'm using a modified version of `matlabfrag` to create a PDF file containing the latex symbols. However I am not able to declare new fonts in Matlab, so my question is: Instead of using the command `\mathpzc{}`, can I use a different (and probably more complex) command which also account for the code I put in the preamble?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: The idea of `matlabfrag` to separate `figure.fig` into `figure.tex`(text) and `figure.eps`(graphic) streams is to give freedom for user to choose `LaTeX` fonts in the preamble of `main.tex`. If you don't need this font freedom,want to seal the `LaTeX` text fonts in `figure.pdf` you can try [mlf2pdf.m--> matlabfrag to create a latex formatted pdf file](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28545) where you can place your preamble of `main.tex`.

Comment: Where in MATLAB do you want the new font. MATLAB treats the axis labels (e.g, what you get with xlabel) from the actual tick marks and their labels.